# Question about 5/4 time signature

Tags: piano

How to count long notes and what is the rule for the 5/4 time signature?

[image]

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Can you be more specific about which notes you're having trouble counting, and what kind of trouble you're having?

Comment: What "long notes"? The pattern is pretty clear: 3/4 + 2/4. Btw, that is **NOT** by Chopin (not even from thousands miles away, luckily, and he's probably still rolling over in his grave), it's "Mariage d'amour" by [Paul de Senneville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_de_Senneville) and usually known as performed by Richard Clayderman - and it's soooo booooring.

Comment: 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & | 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & | 1 e & uh 2 e & uh 3 e & uh 4 e & uh 5 e & uh | 1 e & uh 2 e & uh 3 & 4 & | 1 e & uh 2 e & uh 3 e & uh 4 e & uh | 1 e & uh 2 e & uh 3 & 4 &

Comment: Apart from things others pointed out (It's not by Chopin, there are no long notes) it's also not a waltz and the 5/4 bar is extremely badly notated.

Answer (score 0):

Those long notes look quite short. So, I'll go with that.

5/4 time is generally counted in one of two ways - 3+2, or 2+3. In this example, it's clearly 3+2, lookin at the way the semis and l.h. quavers are joined. That puts emphasis on beat 1, and slightly less on beat 4.

I'd be counting **1**& 2& 3& **4**& 5& but only for that bar, as next it reverts to 4/4, when the emphases are on **1** and **3**.

Then, each of the semis (16th notes) will be twice as fast, or in other words, two fit in the time of one quaver ((eighth notes).

If that doesn't work, then go further into the oft used 1e&a 2e&a 3e&a 4e&a 5e&a, making the first semis (Gs) play on e&. the other repeated notes come on either a2, or e& after that. Slowly slowly is the order of the day, but with a stable count. Metronomes are known to be beneficial.